# projection KKT optimal condition

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Using the KKT optimality condition find the orthogonal projection of an arbitrary point $c \in$  to the closed convex set $C$ (non empty) defined by:

(a) $C=\{x \in R^n : Ax\leq a\}$ where $A\in R^{mxn}$ (surjective) and $a\in R^m$.

(b) For $n=3$, $C=\{x\in R^n:<Ax,x>\leq1\}$ where $A\in R^{3x3}$ is symetric positive defined.

A hint would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: For (a), are you sure that $A$ is surjective? That implies $m\ge n$.